# Rviz trying to display shape_msgs Mesh

Tags: rviz, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

I've created a ROS node that uses a lidar scanner and a pan tilt unit to create 3d scans. These scans are published by the node as shape_msgs::Mesh messages. I was hoping to be able to visualize these meshes live in Rviz as they are created. But they don't seem to be supported by Rvis V1.11.10 in Ros Indigo.

Is there a message type for a mesh that does work in rviz? Ideally I'd like to be able to display texture mapped meshes but I can't find a standard message type that supports that?

At some point soon I'll be needing to display a 3D terrain map in Rvis to if that's possible?

Thanks, Pete

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222362/rviz-trying-to-display-shape_msgs-mesh/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-12-11**:
Could you just use a triangle list type and sort the vertices in your shape_msgs Mesh so they are correctly ordered for the triangle list?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2015-12-17**:
Hi there. Yes I have used the triangle list. Because the data is being generated live so the last thing I want to do is save it to a file.
The messages a huge since vertices have to be repeated many times. But colouring the triangles is a bonus.
Thanks

**Comment by [simaopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32526/simaopp/) on 2018-01-16**:
Can you please tell me how can you create the triangle list to display on rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you want a Mesh Marker: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-12-11**:
Doesn't this type require a mesh file and so can this be done real-time?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-11**:
You're right this would require them to write each mesh out to a file. I think the triangle list is a better approach, as you commented above.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2015-12-17**:
Yup. Thanks. I've used a triangle list in the end

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This rviz plugin displays `shape_msgs::Mesh` and can have a texture projected over it (though haven't gotten the texture working yet), I don't know how good it is for large vertice lists:

https://github.com/lucasw/vigir_ocs_common/tree/master/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugins/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugin_mesh_display_custom

I forked it from https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_ocs_common on the suggestion of the answer to http://answers.ros.org/question/218502/rviz-display-image-in-3d-scene/ and got rid of the most everything except that plugin.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1